# How do I instantiate an object based on the ending of a string? (This is for an L System)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development, l-systems

So I'm working on this L system, and I have it set up like this:

`private const string axiom = "X";`

`private string currentString = string.Empty;`

I am calling a method called Generate.

```
    private void Generate() { currentString = axiom; StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();for(int i=0; i < iterations; i++) {
        //loop through current string and create a new string based on the rules
        foreach (char c in currentString){
            sb.Append(rules.ContainsKey(c) ? rules[c] : c.ToString());
        }

        //Set currentString to the new string we just generated.
        currentString = sb.ToString();
        sb = new StringBuilder();
    }
```

And then I'm using a foreach loop and a switch statement to go through the string, and generate the tree:

```
foreach (char c in currentString) { 
            switch(c){
                case 'F':
                    //Draw a straight line
                    Vector3 initialPosition = transform.position;
                    transform.Translate(Vector3.up * length);
                    GameObject treeSegment;
                    if (currentString[(c + 1) % currentString.Length] == 'X' || 
                        currentString[(c + 4) % currentString.Length] == 'F' && currentString[(c + 5) % currentString.Length] == 'X')
                    {
                         treeSegment = Instantiate(leaf);
                        Debug.Log("LEAF!");
                    }
                    else{
                         treeSegment = Instantiate(branch);
                    }
                    treeSegment.GetComponent<LineRenderer>().SetPosition(0, initialPosition);
                    treeSegment.GetComponent<LineRenderer>().SetPosition(1, transform.position);
                    break;

                case 'X':
                    //does nothing, generate more Fs
                    break;

                case '+':
                    //Rotates clockwise
                    transform.Rotate(Vector3.back * angle);
                    break;

                case '-':
                    //Rotates counter-clockwise
                    transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward * angle);
                    break;

                case '[':
                    //Save current transform info
                    transformStack.Push(new TransformInfo(){
                        position = transform.position,
                        rotation = transform.rotation
                    });
                    break;

                case ']':
                    //Return to our previously saved transform info
                    TransformInfo ti = transformStack.Pop();
                    transform.position = ti.position;
                    transform.rotation = ti.rotation;
                    break;

                default:
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("Invalid L-tree operation");
            }
        }
```

The tutorial which I'm basing this off checks for position to place branches and leaves like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < currentString.Length; i++) 
{
    switch (currentString[i]) 
    { 
        case 'F':
             initialPosition = transform.position; 
             transform.Translate(Vector3.up * 2 * length);

             GameObject fLine = currentString[(i + 1) % currentString.Length] == 'X' || currentString[(i + 3) % currentString.Length] == 'F' && currentString[(i + 4) % currentString.Length] == 'X' ? Instantiate(leaf) : Instantiate(branch);
```

I have no idea what's happening here. I don't get why he's adding seemingly random numbers and then using modulus.

Any help at all will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the original one you are accessing next characters! Like a look ahead with wrap around

```
currentString[(i + 1) % currentString.Length]
```

basically goes to the next index but if the index reaches `currentString.Length` it is wrapped around thanks to the `%` and becomes `0` again.

As an example lets say your string looks like

```
0 1 2 3 4 5
A B C D E F
      |
      | current index = 3
```

Then `(i + 4) % length` would mean `7 % 6`  = `1`

```
0 1 2 3 4 5
A B C D E F
  |
  | new index after shifting 4 with wrap around = 1
```

---

So the entire line

```
GameObject fLine = currentString[(i + 1) % currentString.Length] == 'X' || currentString[(i + 3) % currentString.Length] == 'F' && currentString[(i + 4) % currentString.Length] == 'X' ? Instantiate(leaf) : Instantiate(branch);
```

Basically translates to

- (The current char is an `F`) - from the `switch`
- IF

  - The next char is an `X`
  - OR

    - the char 3 to the right (with wrap around) is an `F`
    - AND the char after that is an `X`
- THEN

  - Instantiate(leaf)
- ELSE

  - Instantiate(branch);

---

**HOWEVER**

In your code you are doing

```
currentString[(c + 1) % currentString.Length]
```

**BUT** `c` is the actual **value** of a character like e.g. `A` == `65`.
It makes absolutely no sense to use this as an index in your original string!

=> You want to stick to a `for` loop in order to have the actual current index of your chracter